# Custom Firebase cell not appearing in TableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, firebase

I am trying to populate a `TableView` with custom cells that have an image in them downloaded from Firebase. The custom cell is not appearing in the Tableview. I believe I configure the cells with an array named 'posts', that is full of  'TimeLinePost', however when I print 'posts.count' for the '`numberOfRows`' func 0 appears, so something is not working somewhere. I may also be making a mistake in how I downloading the data. Any assistance where I am going wrong would be great thanks.

This is the code for the `TableView` and contains the 'TimeLinePost' Class -

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView?
    var posts = [TimeLinePost]()
    private let storage = Storage.storage().reference()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.table?.register(TableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: TableViewCell.identifier)
        table?.delegate = self
        table?.dataSource = self
        table?.reloadData()
        
    }
    


    @IBAction func unwindSegue(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
        
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(posts.count)
        return posts.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCell.identifier, for:indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.configure(with: posts[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

}

    class TimeLinePost {
    var image: String
    
    init (image: String) {
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

This is the code for uploading the data -

```
    struct MyKeys {
    static let imagesFolder = "imagesFolder"
    static let uid = "uid"
    static let imagesURL = "imagesURL"
    static let imagesCollection = "imagesCollection"
}

    class uploadViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    var imageDownloadUrl: String?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!
    var original: UIImage!
    private let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBAction func choosePhoto() {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary){
            let picker = UIImagePickerController()
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            navigationController?.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            photoImageView.image = image
            original = image
            
        }
        
        

    }
    
    @IBAction func uploadPhoto(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let image = photoImageView.image,
            let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
            else {
                print("Error")
                return
                
        }
        
        let imageName = UUID().uuidString
        
        let imageReference = Storage.storage().reference().child("images").child(imageName)
        imageReference.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("Failed to upload")
                return
            }
            
            imageReference.downloadURL{ (url, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error")
                    return
                }
                guard let url = url else {
                    print("Error")
                    return
                }
                
                
                let dataReference = Firestore.firestore().collection(MyKeys.imagesCollection).document()
                let documentUid = dataReference.documentID
                let urlString = url.absoluteString
                
                let data = [
                    MyKeys.uid: documentUid,
                    MyKeys.imagesURL: urlString,
                ]
                
                dataReference.setData(data) { (error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error:\(error)")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(documentUid, forKey: MyKeys.uid)
                    
                    
                    
                    
}

}
}
}
}
```

And this is the code for my custom cell -

```
 class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var imagePost: UIImageView!
    
    static let identifier = "TableViewCell"
    
    static func nib() -> UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
       
        
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    func configure(with posts: TimeLinePost) {
        self.imagePost.image = UIImage(named: posts.image)
    }
    func downloadImage(){
        
        
        guard let uid = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: MyKeys.uid) else {
            print("Error1")
            return
        }
        
        let query = Firestore.firestore().collection(MyKeys.imagesCollection).whereField(MyKeys.uid, isEqualTo: uid)
        
        query.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error2")
                return
            }
            guard let snapshot = snapshot, let data = snapshot.documents.first?.data(), let urlString = data[MyKeys.imagesURL] as? String, let url = URL(string: urlString)  else {
                print("Error3")
                return
            }
            let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: url)
            self.imagePost.kf.setImage(with: resource, completionHandler: { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(_):
                    print("Success")
                    return
                case .failure(_):
                    print("Error4")
                    return
                }
                
                
            })
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You create empty posts array. But I don't see any code where you put something into this array

Comment: In my code for the custom cell, would the 'func configure(with posts:TimeLinePost)' not populate the array with a 'TimeLinePost' when an image is added to it from Firebase? That is how I was seeing it, however I may be a long way off.

Comment: You need to do some better troubleshooting to narrow down the issue; a split-half search will help to determine if this is a Firebase issue or a table/cell issue. Temporarily add a text field to your cell and populate it with some text "hello, world", then run your app. If you see "hello, world" that tells you your tableView and custom cell is operating correctly. If not, then you need to troubleshoot that first. Do some testing and let us know the results.

Comment: Oh, and I am going with @oxigen on their comment. There's nothing that actually populates your dataSource from Firebase. This code `self.imagePost.image = UIImage(named: posts.image)` has nothing to do with your dataSource array.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I attempted adding the text field to the cell but that did not appear when I ran the app, so the issue must definitely be there. Still unsure where the issue could be however.